# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+a_n)$ converges absolutely $\iff\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+a_n) \text{ converges absolutely}
>  \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \text{ converges absolutely}.$$

How to prove this,

Suppose $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \text{ converges absolutely}.$$ Let $u_{n}=a_{n}$ and $v_{n}=\log(1+a_n)$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{u_{n}}{v_{n}}=1>0 \implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+ a_n) \text{ converges absolutely}.$$ How to prove the converse part?

Comment: This is an useful inequality https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: But, interestingly, I believe it is false if you omit "absolutely".

Comment: if $$\lim_{n\to\infty } \log(1+a_n) \not=0 \Longleftrightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty }a_n \not = 0$$ then both series diverge.

Assume that $a_n \to 0$, 
$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{|\log(1+a_n)|}{|a_n|} =\left|\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}\right| = 1$

There is $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$


$\left|\frac{|\log(1+a_n)|}{|a_n|} -1\right|<1/2 \Longleftrightarrow \frac12 |a_n|< |\log(1+a_n)|<\frac32|a_n|$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: From the definition of $\ln'(1),$ we have

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+u)}{u} = 1.$$

Thus there is $a>0$ such that

$$\frac{1}{2}\le \left|\frac{\ln (1+u)}{u}\right| \le \frac{3}{2}$$

for $u\in (-a,a),u\ne0.$

Answer (score 2):

The limit comparison test says that if you have two sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=c$ with $0<c<\infty$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n<\infty$.

So we have to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\vert ln(1+x_n)\vert}{\vert x_n\vert}=c$ with $0<c<\infty$. To do this we observe that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\vert ln(1+x)\vert}{\vert x\vert}=1$ by the L'Hopital Rule. As in any of the two cases ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges absolutely or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ln(1+x_n)$ converges absolutely) we will have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\vert ln(1+x_n)\vert}{\vert x_n\vert}=1$.

Comment: we have to prove what ?

Comment: That's not correct, since we don't know that $x_n \to 0$.

Comment: @Adayah sure we conclude that, since otherwise the sum $\sum_{n=1}^k\ln(1+x_n)$ cannot converge. This and the answer of zhw. should be enough for the converse statement!

Answer (score 1):

[This is essentially from @Guy Fsone's answer. However, it is rewritten in a significantly different way.]

First of all, observe that (by continuity of the exponential function and the logarithm)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty } \log(1+a_n) =0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty }a_n = 0.$$

- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ is **not true**, (note carefully that
  this assumption is fundamentally different from
  "$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq 0$"), then both $\sum_{n=1}^\infty
     |\log(1+a_n)|$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverge.
- Assuming that $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty
     }\frac{|\log(1+a_n)|}{|a_n|} =\left|\lim_{h\to
     0}\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}\right| = 1\tag{1}$$ where we use the fact that
  the derivative of $x\mapsto \log x$ at $x=1$ is $1$ and the
  continuity of the absolute value function. **Without loss of generality, 
  we assume here that $|a_n|>0$ for all $n$.**

  It follows from (1) that there exists $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$

  $$\left|\frac{|\log(1+a_n)|}{|a_n|} -1\right|<1/2 $$ which *implies*
  that  $$ \frac12 |a_n|< |\log(1+a_n)|<\frac32|a_n|~~~\forall ~~~n>n_0
     $$ and thus $$ \frac12 \sum_{n>n_0}|a_n|<
     \sum_{n>n_0}|\log(1+a_n)|<\frac32 \sum_{n>n_0}|a_n|.$$

  This estimate completes the proof.

Comment: this post as changed the form. but the meaning remain the same .  I would like to know what is new here.  Another think is that I do not appriory know how further I can go with details since I we do know who is posting the question : If the Op wanted all the details he should have asked as well. I myself asked many times for further details to some questions that are important to me. Another question why did I received a notification that this post is duplicated post? and where is my original post ?

Comment: @GuyFsone: let me address your question one by one. Please be **patient**.
 (1)"I would like to know what is new here." As it was pointed out by a [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/what-to-do-when-your-posts-are-wrongly-downvoted#comment109787_27243) in meta, the logical structure of your original answer is heavily muddled. Since you have been keeping asking a hard evidence for what is wrong for your answer, let me explain in detail (in the next comment box). Again, please be patient before I finish my typing.

Comment: apart the added details I the logic is the same . the idea is the same the structure has not changed either. I were asked to give further to give further details I would have . but instead got my post deleted and copied

Comment: @GuyFsone: Let $A$ be the statement that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log(1+a_n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge absolutely. Let $B$ be $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(1+a_n)=0$ and let $C$ be $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. The first sentence of your original answer says: $A\Rightarrow (B\Leftrightarrow C)$. Note that this a **true** statement, but does *not* contribute anything to your whole argument since $(B\Leftrightarrow C)$ is true regardless $A$ is true or not. (cont.)

Comment: @GuyFsone: (cont.) What you really want to say is $A\Rightarrow (B\hbox{ and } C)$. This is **not** a word playing game. **This is a serious *logic* issue**: "$A\Rightarrow (B\Leftrightarrow C)$" and "$A\Rightarrow (B\text{ and } C)$" are **fundamentally different**.  (I'm still typing. Be patient.)

Comment: if= right arrow.  only if = left arrow please change first the way . and  it was explained in the next line that if B and B are not true then does not make sense to study A .

Comment: my A statement is the following . A = it makes sense to study the series a_n and b_ n . that is my A statement not what you are claiming.  B and C statement correspond to the converged to 0 as well . don't change my idea. don't force me to accept what I never said

Comment: @GuyFsone I have already explained in detail what is wrong with your writing in your answer, which has serious logic problems. Your several comments show that you don't understand what I'm talking about at all and it seems that you don't want to. Without a commitment to [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic), there is no way going on a meaningful discussion. If you want to insist that you are writing a correct thing and keep yelling how wrong others are, it is certainly your right. I will stop here.

Comment: @GuyFsone: (2) "Another question why did I received a notification that this post is duplicated post? and where is my original post ?" It is simply because you were duplicating *your own* post.

Comment: please don't take your anger over you. Why did you more simply edit my post instead of copying and past? me too I am tired of this discussion . because I feel my post was stolen. but a post which was supposed to be wrong with heavy mathematical mistakes .I seriously loved the down votes for that post

Comment: @Jack: While most of what you say is correct, I have an alternative explanation for what is happening: Guy Fsone is not a native speaker of English, and this is painfully seen in his awkward and sometimes seemingly illogical formulations. What I'm saying is that the same answers formulated in his own native language would probably be correct.

Comment: How are the statements $(1)$ "$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ is not true" and $(2)$ "$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\ne 0$" fundamentally different?

Answer (score -1):

My way:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(a_n+1) = \log\prod_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+1)$$
since the series converges absolutely so does the product. Hence $a_n +1 \rightarrow 1$ and so $a_n \rightarrow 0$.
Now the nontrivial step: $a_n \rightarrow 0$, and in proximity of $0$ you have $\log(1+x) = x + o(x^2)$ so dividing by $x$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ exists $n$ such that
$$\frac{|\log(a_n+1)|}{|a_n|} \leq 1+ \epsilon$$
or in other words
$$(1-\epsilon)|a_n| \leq |\log(a_n+1)| \leq (1+\epsilon)|a_n|$$
Apply the sum to the last inequality and you'll prove the proposition both ways.